# Basics question: How can I convert a list vector to a table with R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a pretty basic question I haven't been able to find the answer to because I'm not 100% clear on exactly how to ask it.  The tutorials I found that seem appropriate are all a little too simplified and missing some key info.
I have a list vector of processed data and I'm trying to convert it to a table for downstream analysis and I'm stuck.
Currently I have a Values list with 4088 numerical datapoint.  The metadata of 'Data' has my subtype information. I generated my list this way:

```
vec <-vector("list",3)
vec[[1]] <- Values[which(colData(Data)$Type=="Type1")] 
vec[[2]] <- Values[which(colData(Data)$Type=="Type2")] 
vec[[3]] <- Values[which(colData(Data)$Type=="Type3")]
```

Now, [[1]] has just the values I care about for Type 1, [[2]] for type 2 etc.
So, how do I convert this into a dataframe or a table for downstream stuff like T-Tests between groups?  The below readout tells me I need to define my data somehow and that I have a different number of points per group is a problem, but I'm completely lost here.

```
df <- as.data.frame(vec)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1461, 658, 1969
```

Thanks for any help, or just a direction to a tutorial that will help me answer this for myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually a few options that you can use.

```
#base R
data.frame(lapply(vec, "length<-", max(lengths(vec))))

#Data Table
library(data.table)
setDT(lapply(vec, "length<-", max(lengths(vec))))
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks!
But, if you don't mind, why does it work?  
As near as I can tell:
So lapply = apply to the whole list
length<- will set the length of the list to max(lengths(vec)
So why does that resolve the errors with the data frame generation?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what your downstream steps are, but you can generate a `data.frame` with the maximum length of `lengths(vec)` for the number of rows (which will pad the vectors with `NA` - make sure how to handle NAs afterwards). Examples of how to get such a `data.frame` can be found in the answer of @AndyBrown

Specifically, to perform t-tests between groups you do not need to generate a `data.frame`. You could use pairwise combinations of your list elements, which can have different lengths.
Below is an example using all pairwise combinations of list elements of `vec` to perform t-tests:

```r
lapply(combn(vec, 2, simplify=FALSE), function(x) t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!